# CSRF filter blocks all http post in angularJs

Tags: angularjs, http, playframework, csrf

To secure my application and for authentication I'm using Silhouette, I don't know how to manage my csrf filter did silhouette manage csrf tokens automatically or not? if yes why all my $http request (for uploading a file) from angulars are blocked if no what should I do to enable my http request

Comment: You'd need to pass the CSRF token along with the Ajax request. Maybe this would help? http://nickcarroll.me/2013/02/11/protect-your-play-application-with-the-csrf-filter/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't already, check out the example:

https://github.com/mohiva/play-silhouette-angular-seed

Note:

- create the Filters.scala class: https://github.com/mohiva/play-silhouette-angular-seed/blob/master/app/utils/Filters.scala
- filters are registered in application.conf: https://github.com/mohiva/play-silhouette-angular-seed/blob/master/conf/application.conf#L25
- also, they configure filters in the application.conf: https://github.com/mohiva/play-silhouette-angular-seed/blob/master/conf/application.conf#L59